# Why are the properties of my object not in a chronological order?

Tags: javascript, object

```js
const arr = [4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 2, 3, 1];

let object = {};
object[arr[4]] = 0;
object[arr[3]] = 0;
object[arr[7]] = 0;

console.log(object)
```

[check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRneY.png)

Why are the keys of the object not in the chronological order? I thought the output would be something like this`{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}`

Comment: "I thought the output would be something like.." - what reference documentation leads to that conclusion? Read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects eg. What documentation *doesn't specify* is as important to keep in mind as what it *does*.

Comment: "chronological order" --- a JS object is a collection of key-value pairs, you specified the keys and their corresponding values.

Comment: I'm just confused about why the properties are not in chronological order. If it was an array, then that would be the case, right?

Comment: An object is not an array so.. wouldn't expect a fish to have legs either.

Comment: Well, an array is an object.

Comment: According to the ES6+ specs, the order of integer keys is ascending. Just like with arrays.

Comment: An array is an object indeed. `let object = {};` - this is not an array though.

Comment: all objects are not array

Comment: @FitriRozi And? That is the *same logical error* as this: A human is a mammal. Humans can speak. Therefor mammals can speak.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: The bigger question is why does it matter to you? If you want things in a certain order that is why arrays exist.

Comment: @gforce301 also, Map - that preserves insertion order by spec.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. When iterating over map object, it returns keys in order of insertion